# Get value from attr view in modal - MVC js

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

It is possible to post data-element-id value to modal?
I tried to get $id but I'm not sure why this working for attr but I can't post $id in method in next  (ex postMethod($id).
Can someone please explain me how this work. Thank you.

[image: photo1]

Comment: I think it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

I found solution
**js**

```
   function goDoSomething(identifier) {

   alert("data-id:" + $(identifier).data('element-id'));
}
```